# Functions not firing within react-bootstrap element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-bootstrap

The issue is that my redux-form inside the `react-bootstrap` tab (in `ProductReviewWidget`) doesn't handle any events - checkboxes, `react-dropzone`, submitting the form itself, etc. Even `onClick` listeners don't fire up.

```
render() {
  const { product, reviews, questions } = this.props;
  const productId = product.num_iid;
  let reviews_count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < (reviews[productId] || []).length; i++){
    if(!reviews[productId][i].only_vote){
      reviews_count ++;
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Tab.Container activeKey={this.state.activeTab} onSelect={this.setActiveTab} id="main_tab">
        <div className='text-center clearfix'>
          <Nav bsStyle="pills" bsClass='flex-container flex-start'>
            <NavItem eventKey="review" className="flex-item product-tab-link-item">
              Reviews ({(reviews_count)})
            </NavItem>
          </Nav>
          <Tab.Content className="clearfix" animation data-toggle={"tab"} unmountOnExit={true} id="inner_tab">
            <Tab.Pane eventKey="review" unmountOnExit={true}>
              <ProductReviewWidget product={product} translations={this.props.translations} getTranslation={this.props.getTranslation}/>
            </Tab.Pane>
          </Tab.Content>
        </div>
      </Tab.Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, everything works fine when I move it out of the bootstrap tab like so:

```
render() {
  const { product, reviews, questions } = this.props;
  const productId = product.num_iid;
  let reviews_count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < (reviews[productId] || []).length; i++){
    if(!reviews[productId][i].only_vote){
      reviews_count ++;
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <ProductReviewWidget product={product} translations={this.props.translations} getTranslation={this.props.getTranslation}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps. But, have you tried debugging `<Tab.Content>` and `<Tab.Pane>` to see if they are capturing the events in the first place? One reason I can think of is that the Tab pane is not propagating  the event to <ProductReviewWidget>

Answer (score 0):

Check your styles also, maybe your tab is on your component and It doesn't allow to use your component or fire events because your are clicking or whatever on your tab. Also, you can try using the das property z-index.

I hope you can find the problem